# Open a link in form of pop up in <a asp-action>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I searched in many links, but I don't understand how to change my code, so that after clicking on link, the new page is opened like a pop up. 
I have the following:

```
<a asp-controller = "News" asp-action="CreateSimple" asp-route-id="@Model.Seite.SeitenID">
```

I want the new window to be opened like a pop up.

Someone has suggested sth like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#NewBrowserBtn').on('click', function () {
        window.open('/Home/CreatePartialView', '_blank', 'left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
    });
});
```

But I don't know how to set the asp-controller, asp-action, and asp-route-id parameters here.

Comment: instead of Home put news its controller ,instead of CreatePartialView put CreateSimple its action and after that add "/your_routeid/

Comment: @MangeshAuti thanks a lot for your answer. So you mean like this:$('#NewBrowserBtn').on('click', function () {
        window.open(‘/News/CreateSimple/@Model.Seite.SeitenID/', '_blank', 'left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0');

Comment: And one more thing. Where should I give the an id name to the link? i.e. how should I now change me <a asp...>

Comment: What do u mean by id name to the link?